# Split the string by "|"

Tags: php

Hi I am trying to over come a small issue that I am getting, it seems it will not allow me to split a Cookie

basicly I have a cookie stored that has session|userid

I want to be able to get the session part of that cookie

I have tried everything I now, but seems nothing wants to work.

```
$this->stringer = $_COOKIE["_now_Session"];
$array=preg_split('@|@',$this->stringer);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no need for preg_split here, simply use [explode](http://php.net/explode):

```
$aData = explode("|", $_COOKIE['_now_Session']);
echo $aData[0]; // session
echo $aData[1]; // userid
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$array=explode('|',$this->stringer);
```

Manual:
[explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Answer (score 3):

> $array=preg_split('@|@', $this->stringer);

Why use preg_split in the first place? I'd use explode for this, really:

```
<?php
list( $session, $userid ) = explode( '|' , $_COOKIE['_now_Session'] );
```

Comment: I think you miss the delimiter in first argument.

Comment: @OZ_, thanks for the edit. @Brice, thanks for the heads up :)